# Choosing the meshes in a circuit with a given tree

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have to use mesh analysis to write down the independent mesh equations. I already did this with the same circuit but with a different tree. Now I have to do it with this tree, and I have no clue how to take the meshes correctly. Can someone give me a hint?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are:

- links = branches not part of the tree (i.e. the cotree)
- each mesh = closed by taking exactly one link (rest is from the tree)

So if you take R1 as link you get the mesh along R1, R2, Uq2. Then if you take R3 as link you get R3, R2, Uq2, Uq1. Finally, if you take Uq3 as link, you get your last mesh which goes around the outer perimeter.

[image]